# Error converting data type varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a table with a column as `varchar`. This column can hold numbers or text. During certain queries I treat it as a `bigint` column (I do a join between it and a column in another table that is `bigint`)

As long as there were only numbers in this field had no trouble but the minute even one row had text and not numbers in this field I got a "Error converting data type `varchar` to `bigint`." error even if in the WHERE part I made sure none of the text fields came up.

To solve this I created a view as follows:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT ID, CAST(MyCol AS bigint) AS MyCol
FROM         MyTable
WHERE     (isnumeric(MyCol) = 1)
```

But even though the view shows only the rows with numeric values and casts Mycol to bigint I still get a *Error converting data type varchar to bigint* when running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyView where mycol=1
```

When doing queries against the view it shouldn't know what is going on behind it! it should simply see two bigint fields! ([see attached image](http://www.getprice.com.au/view.gif), even mssql management studio shows the view fields as being bigint)

Comment: Personally I think you are fixing the wrong problem. Something is wrong with your schema/database design if you are using one column for two different purposes.

Comment: Yes, I know but the whole system is too far along to make major changes now

Comment: Following link has some details on this: [sql-server-peculiar-issue-error-converting-varchar-to-bigint](http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/sql-server-peculiar-issue-error-converting-varchar-to-bigint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. I finally created a view that works:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT id, CAST(CASE WHEN IsNumeric(MyCol) = 1 THEN MyCol ELSE NULL END AS bigint) AS MyCol
FROM         dbo.MyTable
WHERE     (MyCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
```

Thanks to **AdaTheDev** and **CodeByMoonlight**. I used your two answers to get to this. (Thanks to the other repliers too of course)

Now when I do joins with other bigint cols or do something like 'SELECT * FROM MyView where mycol=1' it returns the correct result with no errors. My guess is that the CAST in the query itself causes the query optimizer to not look at the original table as Christian Hayter said may be going on with the other views

Comment: If you are still satisfied that this answer is the most correct, then you should accept it as The Answer.  This will remove your question from the list of still open questions.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you want to try to avoid storing the data in this form - would be worth splitting the BIGINT data out in to a separate column for both performance and ease of querying.

However, you can do a JOIN like this example. Note, I'm **not using ISNUMERIC()** to determine if it's a valid BIGINT because that would validate incorrect values which would cause a conversion error (e.g. decimal numbers).

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyCol VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @OtherTable TABLE (Id BIGINT)

INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('1')
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('Text')
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('1 and some text')
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('1.34')
INSERT @MyTable VALUES ('2')
INSERT @OtherTable VALUES (1)
INSERT @OtherTable VALUES (2)
INSERT @OtherTable VALUES (3)

SELECT *
FROM @MyTable m
    JOIN @OtherTable o ON CAST(m.MyCol AS BIGINT) = o.Id
WHERE m.MyCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

**Update:**
The only way I can find to get it to work for having a WHERE clause for a specific integer value without doing another CAST() on the supposedly bigint column in the where clause too, is to use a user defined function:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBigIntRecordsOnly]()
RETURNS @Results TABLE (BigIntCol BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT @Results
SELECT CAST(MyCol AS BIGINT)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
RETURN
END

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnBigIntRecordsOnly]() WHERE BigIntCol = 1
```

I don't really think this is a great idea performance wise, but it's a solution

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question about the error message: when you reference a view name in another query (assuming it's a traditional view not a materialised view), SQL Server effectively does a macro replacement of the view definition into the consuming query and then executes that.

The advantage of doing this is that the query optimiser can do a much better job if it sees the whole query, rather than optimising the view separately as a "black box".

A consequence is that if an error occurs, error descriptions may look confusing because the execution engine is accessing the underlying tables for the data, not the view.

I'm not sure how materialised views are treated, but I would imagine that they are treated like tables, since the view data is cached in the database.

Having said that, I agree with previous answers - you should re-think your table design and separate out the text and integer data values into separate columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your view to this :

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ID, 
Cast(Case When IsNumeric(MyCol) = 1 Then MyCol Else null End AS bigint) AS MyCol
FROM MyTable
WHERE (IsNumeric(MyCol) = 1)
```

Comment: sorry this query returned same 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint' err

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? I've tried this in SQL2000 and up without any issues.
Glad you found a solution, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert other table's bigint field into varchar? As for me it makes sense to perform more robust conversion... It shouldn't affect your performance too much if varchar field is indexed.

Comment: That may be a solution, but what really intrigued me here was getting the error on the view even though it had only bigint fields

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a redundant bigint field to hold the integer value of af MyCol.

You may then index the new field to speed up the join.

Comment: This would mean changing large portions of my project to select the correct field each time...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the select in 2 stages.

first create a view that selects all columns where my col is nummeric.

Then do a select in that view where you cast the varchar field.

The other thing you could look at is your design of tables to remove the need for the cast.

EDIT

- Are some of the numbers larger than bigint?
- Are there any spaces, leading, trailing or in the number?
- Are there any format characters? Decimal points?

Comment: Tried. I Still get the same error even when querying second view

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  CAST(MyCol AS bigint) as MyCol
FROM
(
  SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
      ID, 
      MyCol 
  FROM 
      MyTable 
  WHERE 
      (isnumeric(MyCol) = 1)
) as tmp
```

This should work since the inner select only return numeric values and the outer select can therefore convert all values from the first select into a numeric. It seems that in your own code SQL tries to cast before executing the isnumeric function (maybe it has something to do with optimizing).

Comment: Your query indeed returns only the rows with numbers. but when turning it into a view and querying the view I get the same 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint' (only when doing " where mycol=1" i get the error)