# Using SQL 2005 trying to cast 16 digit Varchar as Bigint error converting

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, types

First, thanks for all your help! You really make a difference, and I GREATLY appreciate it.

So I have a Varchar column and it holds a 16 digit number, example: 1000550152872026

```
select *
FROM Orders 
where isnumeric([ord_no]) = 0
```

> returns: 0 rows

---

```
select cast([ord_no] as bigint)
FROM Progression_PreCall_Orders o
order by [ord_no]
```

> returns: Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

How do I get this 16 digit number into a math datatype so I can add and subtract another column from it?

UPDATE: Found scientific notation stored as varchar ex: 1.00054E+15

How do I convert that back into a number then?

Comment: Does this query return anything: `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ord_no LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`?

Comment: @Andriy M wow it does! 3k rows!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DECIMAL datatype seems to work fine:

```
DECLARE @myVarchar AS VARCHAR(32)
SET @myVarchar = '1000550152872026'

DECLARE @myDecimal AS DECIMAL(38,0)
SET @myDecimal = CAST(@myVarchar AS DECIMAL(38,0))
SELECT @myDecimal + 1
```

Also, here's a quick example where `IsNumeric` returns `1` but converting to DECIMAL fails:

```
DECLARE @myVarchar AS VARCHAR(32)
SET @myVarchar = '1000550152872026E10'
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@myVarchar)

DECLARE @myDecimal AS DECIMAL(38,0)
SET @myDecimal = CAST(@myVarchar AS DECIMAL(38,0)) --This statement will fail
```

**EDIT**
You could try to `CONVERT` to float if you're dealing with values written in scientific notation:

```
DECLARE @Orders AS TABLE(OrderNum NVARCHAR(64), [Date] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES('100055015287202', GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES('100055015287203', GETDATE())
INSERT INTO @Orders VALUES('1.00055015287E+15', GETDATE()) --sci notation

SELECT 
    CONVERT(FLOAT, OrderNum, 2) + 
    CAST(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120), '-', '') AS FLOAT)
FROM @Orders
```

Comment: Error converting data type varchar to numeric :: is what I get :(

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome Updated my answer to show that you can convert the number from your question into a DECIMAL. The problem could be related to the fact that IsNumeric can return 1 for results that you might not expect. Can you find which row your query is failing on?

Comment: I can't seem to, I've tried several things. I know for sure that the number is always 16 digits stored as a varchar.

Comment: If I just select the column though it uses scientific notation - if that helps.

Comment: Yep, that will cause a problem, since `IsNumeric` will return true for those records but attempting to CAST those values to DECIMAL will fail. Can you update the question with some of the values in that column that have the scientific notation? These are `NVARCHAR` values too, right?

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome See the update to my answer. I think that last example might work for you. I converted the order num to a float and added a date value to it (in the format YYYYMMDD).

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH validOrds AS
(
    SELECT ord_no
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE ord_no NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
)
SELECT  cast(validOrds.ord_no as bigint) as  ord_no
FROM    validOrds
        LEFT JOIN Orders ords
            ON ords.ord_no = validOrds.ord_no
WHERE   ords.ord_no is null
```

Take a look at this link for an explanation of why isnumeric isn't functioning the way you are assuming it would: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/

Take a look at this link for an SO post where a user has a similar problem as you:
 [Error converting data type varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237784/error-converting-data-type-varchar)

hence, you should always use the correct datatype for each column unless you have a very specific reason to do so otherwise... Even then, you'll need to be extra careful when saving values to the column to ensure that they are indeed valid values

Comment: wow, I never even thought I had to break it down to what isnumeric() =1 ! my god, how am I going to explain that I didn't know what goes into a seemingly self explanatory function to my boss.

Comment: @CodingIsAwesome No one knows how that function works until they run into an issue like this one... =)

Comment: @rsbarro, and then you save that link in your favorites :D