# Error while using Union in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I am trying to combine same information from 2 views and both queries individually are producing results. However, as soon as I use Union to combine them, it gives error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

I have tried using alias for table name as well but it shows the same error.

Here is my query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       syn.sourcename,
       syn.propertyname,
       syn.IATA,
       syn.iataagencyname,
       syn.iataagencyaffiliation,
       syn.nightsstayed,
       syn.reservationstatus,
       syn.departuredate,
       syn.reservationroomrate
FROM dbo.vwIATAfactreservationSynXis syn
WHERE syn.reservationstatus != 'C'
  AND syn.departuredate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2020')
  AND syn.departuredate <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
       ws.sourcename,
       ws.propertyname,
       ws.IATA,
       ws.iataagencyname,
       ws.iataagencyaffiliation,
       ws.nightsstayed,
       ws.reservationstatus,
       ws.departuredate,
       ws.reservationroomrate
FROM dbo.vwIATAfactreservationSHR ws
WHERE ws.reservationstatus != 'C'
  AND ws.departuredate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2020')
  AND ws.departuredate <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE());
```

Comment: One of the columns in the select list is a different type between the 2 different queries. SQL will try and convert to the more precise type i.e. bigint. You should check the datatypes and explicitly cast the bigint to a varchar in the query.

Comment: your column datatype is different in two tables, for union/union all operators the structure of the table need to be compatible

Comment: Why use `DISTINCT` when you're already using `UNION`?

Comment: can you provide the create table statements. Also may be this answer will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237784/error-converting-data-type-varchar

Comment: Why do you have two _almost_ identical tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to figure out which columns are not the same . . . and then convert them.  You can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` for this purpose:

```
select column_name, data_type, count(*)
from information_schema.columns c
where table_name in ('vwIATAfactreservationSynXis', 'vwIATAfactreservationSHR')
group by column_name, data_type
having count(*) <> 2
order by column_name;
```

This should be close enough (unless the two views have zillions of columns not mentioned in the query).  If there are lots of singleton columns, then filter on the columns used in the original query. Then, whatever columns have different types -- well, the integer should be converted to a string.

If you don't want to go through that bother, you can just convert all columns in both subqueries -- or all suspect columns -- to strings:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), syn.sourcename) as sourcename,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), syn.propertyname) as proprtyname,
       . . .
```

Comment: Thank you, changed the data type and it worked for me.

Comment: @Vaibhav . . . I find it odd then that you did not accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

try casting the fields in both select statements to string one by one to find the field that is making the problem like the sample below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       cast(syn.sourcename as nvarchar(max)),
       syn.propertyname,
       syn.IATA,
       syn.iataagencyname,
       syn.iataagencyaffiliation,
       syn.nightsstayed,
       syn.reservationstatus,
       syn.departuredate,
       syn.reservationroomrate
FROM dbo.vwIATAfactreservationSynXis syn
WHERE syn.reservationstatus != 'C'
  AND syn.departuredate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2020')
  AND syn.departuredate <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE())
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
       cast(syn.sourcename as nvarchar(max)),
       ws.propertyname,
       ws.IATA,
       ws.iataagencyname,
       ws.iataagencyaffiliation,
       ws.nightsstayed,
       ws.reservationstatus,
       ws.departuredate,
       ws.reservationroomrate
FROM dbo.vwIATAfactreservationSHR ws
WHERE ws.reservationstatus != 'C'
  AND ws.departuredate >= CONVERT(datetime, '01/01/2020')
  AND ws.departuredate <= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE());
```

Comment: There's still, however, no need for the `DISTINCT` keywords in the `SELECT` when the query is using a `UNION`. Their use just causes additional overhead for the data engine.